# Django Email to multiple users

Tags: django, email

What's the best way to send Email via Django.
For example: If I have to send a single message to 20000 emails.
1. Send them on by one?
2. Send them in batches?
3. Not open too many connection to the relay server that we are using.
4. etc

My final goal is:
1. Less load on server where django is running
2. Less load on the relay server
3. Send all emails quickly

Thanks for Help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the mass mail method - or, use a third party service:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/#send-mass-mail

Good luck.

Comment: I was reading the same section but was not sure if this is best solution.  
I ended up using EmailMessage class directly. Thanks for the response!